# Applicative functor that reverses order of effects

Tags: haskell, terminology, functor, applicative

Given an applicative functor `f`, I had an idea of making a new applicative functor `Rev f` like `f` but with the order of effects reversed. Here it is:

```
import Control.Applicative

newtype Rev f a = Rev {unRev :: f a}

instance Functor f => Functor (Rev f) where
  fmap f (Rev fx) = Rev (fmap f fx)

instance Applicative f => Applicative (Rev f) where
  pure x = Rev (pure x)
  (Rev ff) <*> (Rev fx) = Rev (pure (\x f -> f x) <*> fx <*> ff)
```

My questions are

1. Is that a valid `Applicative` instance (does it obey the `Applicative` laws)?
2. Does this construction have a name? Is there a module somewhere this is hiding in?

Comment: If you're interested in `Backwards` applicative functors, you may also like `Data.Functor.Reverse`, which folds and traverses backwards. You may also find the `tardis` state transformer interesting.

Answer (score 12):

The friendly folks on IRC pointed to the [`Backwards`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.4.3.0/docs/Control-Applicative-Backwards.html) applicative offered by the `transformers` package. You may also like the [`(<**>)`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#v:-60--42--42--62-) operator available in the standard library.